# snowflake python API: SELECT JSON in VARIANT column: always the same output in the API?

Tags: python, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON string that I insert into a VARIANT column using the "select trick":

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO MYDATA (txid,jdata)                                       
    SELECT column1 as txid,                                                        
           parse_json(column2) as jdata                                                       
    from values (%s,%s);
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (my_txid,some_json_string))
```

This works fine and allows me to use the colon and dotpath operators to dig through the JSON.
The order of the key-value pairs at any particular level is non-deterministic and this is OK and is well-documented.  My question is it non-deterministic upon input and output or just input?  I have examples where this input JSON:

```
{ "bbb":"val2", "aaaa":"val1", "c":"val3"}
```

is returned via `SELECT` into the driver as follows:

```
cur.execute(f"SELECT TXID, JDATA FROM MYDATA WHERE TXID = %s",(txid,))
row = cur.fetchone()
rdata = row[1]
print(rdata.__class__, "\n", rdata)
<class 'str'>
{
  "aaaa": "val1",
  "bbb": "val2",
  "c": "val3"
}
```

EDIT:
In fact, the reordering/reformatting appears to be a key sort with indent level 2, exactly what

```
json.dumps(doc,indent=2,sort_keys=True)
```

would produce and this has been tested on much more complex structures than the example above.  This reordering appears stable, i.e. it is always fetched this way.   Is this true?  Note that very specifically we are *not* calling `TO_JSON` above; we wish to capture the "raw VARIANT."

If it is true that JSON-in-a-VARIANT is always vended the same way in SELECT (assuming no TO_JSON() or other manipulation) then this could lead to powerful and useful secondary capabilities like storing a SHA3 of the VARIANT as a peer column.

Comment: Snowflake experts: opine?